# Does Clojure have short-circuit logic?

Tags: optimization, clojure, short-circuiting

In many languages, if you write something along the lines of

```
if (foo() || bar() || foobar()) { /* do stuff */ }
```

and foo() returns true, then bar() and foobar() will not be evaluated.

Suppose I had the following Clojure code:

```
(let [a (simple-function args)
      b (complex-function args)
      c (too-lazy-to-optimize-this-function args)]
  (or a b c))
```

If a evaluates to true, will b and c also be evaluated, or will they be ignored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you answered your own question, note that though in your example b and c may not evaluated in the (or a b c) call, the let binding is evaluated before that so the too-lazy-to-optimize-this-function call is evaluated anyway. Clojure isn't as lazy as that.

To be clear: to conditionally evaluate the function calls, you need to put the expression evaluating them in the `or` call, basically:

```
(or (simple-function args)
    (complex-function args)
    (too-lazy-to-optimize-this-function args))
```

Comment: I'm accepting this one because it discusses gotcha that I was unaware of.

Comment: It's not a gotcha, rather you have to understand everything is eager except lazy sequences, and the functions that work on them.  The 'or' short-circuits since it's a macro, it expands to http://bit.ly/u8xnms .  If it were a function, it would evaluate its arguments.  Instead, it macroexpands to an if, which is a special form and short-circuits.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers all good, but when in doubt, you can always just test it out on the REPL:

```
user=> (or true (do (println "hello") true))
true
user=> (or false (do (println "hello") true))
hello
true
```

Answer (score 4):

When in doubt, consult [the documentation](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/or):

> or
>   macro
>   Usage:
>
> ```
>    (or)  
>    (or x)  
>    (or x & next)
> ```
>
> Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
>   returns a logical true value, or returns that value **and doesn't
>   evaluate any of the other expressions**, otherwise it returns the
>   value of the last expression. (or) returns nil.

(Emphasis mine.)

The [documentation for `and`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/and) shows it behaves in the equivalent way too.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I finished typing this question, I realized I could just look at the documentation for 'or'.

From the docs: 
 "Evaluates exprs one at a time, from left to right. If a form
  returns a logical true value, or returns that value and doesn't
  evaluate any of the other expressions, otherwise it returns the
  value of the last expression. (or) returns nil."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Clojure does indeed have short circuit evaluation.

One interesting feature in Clojure / other Lisps is that it is also possible to extend the language with new constructs that also provide short-circuit evaluation. This can't be done using functions in most other languages since all the parameters to a function must be evaluated before the function is called.

Here's an example of a macro to implement a short-circuiting NAND function in Clojure:

```
(defmacro nand 
  ([x] 
    `(not ~x))              ; NAND is equivalent to NOT for one argument
  ([x & xs] 
    `(let [nand# (not ~x)]
       (if nand# 
         true               ; short circuit if we can prove the nand is true
         (nand ~@xs)))))    ; continue with the other expressions otherwise

(nand true true)
=> false

(nand false (println "Expression with a side effect!"))
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (foo() || bar() || foobar()) { /* do stuff */ }
```

to

```
(if (or (foo) (bar) (boobar)) (comment do stuff))
```

or

```
(when (or (foo) (bar) (boobar)) (comment do stuff))
```